# can't compile avahi on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am a newbie in cross compilation and I was assigned the task to use the android patch http://avahi.org/ticket/354 to compile avahi core to android.
ndk-build avahi-configure V=1 was successful, but when I ran: ndk-build V=1 NDK_LOG=2 APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a", it gives tons of warning and also make error on socket.o

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Error:
    /home/ruoruo/Software/android-
ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/if.h:85:12: warning: comma at end of enumerator list [-pedantic]
    /home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/if.h:90:22: warning: comma at end of enumerator list [-pedantic]
    /home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c:68:8: error: redefinition of 'struct in6_pktinfo'
    /home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/linux      /ipv6.h:21:8: note: originally defined here
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c: In function 'avahi_mdns_mcast_join_ipv6':
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c:150:64: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c: In function 'avahi_recv_dns_packet_ipv4':
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c:647:9: warning: variable 'found_addr' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c: In function 'avahi_recv_dns_packet_ipv6':
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c:809:24: warning: variable 'found_iface' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni/avahi-core/socket.c:809:9: warning: variable 'found_ttl' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make: *** [/home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/obj/local/armeabi/objs/avahi-core/socket.o] Error 1

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

AVAHI_TOP := /home/ruoruo/Software/android-ndk-r8b/samples/avahi_exports/jni
CONFIGURE := configure
CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS := -lc -ldl

AVAHI_BUILT_SOURCES := \
    avahi-common/Android.mk \
    avahi-core/Android.mk \
    avahi-client-uninstalled.pc \
    avahi-client/Android.mk \
    avahi-utils/Android.mk \
    avahi-glib/Android.mk \
    avahi-glib-uninstalled.pc \
    avahi-gobject/Android.mk \
    avahi-gobject-uninstalled.pc \
    avahi-daemon/Android.mk

avahi-configure-real:
    cd $(AVAHI_TOP) ; \
#    CC="$(CONFIGURE_CC)" \
#    CFLAGS="$(CONFIGURE_CFLAGS)" \
#    LD=$(TARGET_LD) \
    LDFLAGS="$(CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS)" \
#    CPP=$(CONFIGURE_CPP) \
#    CPPFLAGS="$(CONFIGURE_CPPFLAGS)" \
#    PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$(CONFIGURE_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR) \17
#    PKG_CONFIG_TOP_BUILD_DIR=$(PKG_CONFIG_TOP_BUILD_DIR) \
    $(AVAHI_TOP)/$(CONFIGURE) --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
    --disable-nls --disable-gtk --disable-gtk3 \
    --disable-dbus --disable-python \
    --disable-xmltoman --with-xml=none \
    --disable-glib --disable-gobject --disable-qt3 --disable-qt4 \
    --disable-gdbm --disable-libdaemon \
    --with-distro=none --disable-core-docs \
    --disable-Werror
    echo "before make file"
    for file in $(AVAHI_BUILT_SOURCES); do \
       rm -f $$file && \
        make -C $$(dirname $$file) $$(basename $$file) ; \
    done

    avahi-configure: avahi-configure-real

    .PHONY: avahi-configure

    CONFIGURE_TARGETS += avahi-configure

    #include all the subdirs...
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-common/Android.mk
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-client/Android.mk
    -include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-core/Android.mk
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-daemon/Android.mk
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-glib/Android.mk
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-gobject/Android.mk
    #-include $(AVAHI_TOP)/avahi-utils/Android.mk

#generate libavahi.so and libavahi.a
LOCAL_MODULE    := avahi_static
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libavahi
-include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avahi_shared
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libavahi
-include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patch you have downloaded is not up-to-date. The latest NDK, r8b, contains the file `linux/ipv6.h` which could not be found on the earlier versions of NDK. Unfortunately this change to NDK, welcome as it is, has never been documented.

This means that you must undo the patch to `socket.c` file, by removing the lines

```
67  #ifdef __BIONIC__ 
68  struct in6_pktinfo { 
69      struct in6_addr ipi6_addr; 
70      int ipi6_ifindex; 
71  }; 
72  #endif 
73
```

from `avahi-core/socket.c` file.

Comment: nicely done! It works! Could you also tell me how did you identify the root cause?

Comment: I happen to keep few older versions of NDK on my local disk, so it was easy to find that the `linux/ipv6.h` header only appeared recently. Then I looked at the patch you linked, and found that it was submitted before NDK r8b became available.

Comment: If you are registered on [avahi.org](http://avahi.org), you are welcome to send an update, so that future generations have easier lives.

Comment: Maybe you can help this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991668/problems-compiling-avahi-into-android-ndk-project

Answer (score 0):

Create `Application.mk` with the following content:

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-7
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_MODULES := avahi_static
```

Then omit `APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a"` in your `ndk-build` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.tar avahi-0.6.31
2.patch -p1 < 0001-Add-Android-support.patch (http://avahi.org/ticket/354)
patch -p1 < 0002-Add-uninstalled.pc.in-files.patch 

3.cd avahi-0.6.31 ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var make 

4.cd the subdirectories make Android.mk 

then,you will see Android.mk in all the subdirectories.


5.ndk-build V=1 NDK_LOG=2 APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a"
```