# how to get Android.mk when compile avahi on android,

Tags: android, avahi

I was assigned the task to use the android patch http://avahi.org/ticket/354 to compile avahi core to android. 
After i use the patch ,there are no Android.mk files present in any of the Avahi subdirectories (like \avahi-core etc).How can i get them.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's the same situation, but have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991668/problems-compiling-avahi-into-android-ndk-project)?

Answer (score 0):

1.tar avahi-0.6.31 2.patch -p1 < 0001-Add-Android-support.patch patch -p1 < 0002-Add-uninstalled.pc.in-files.patch 3.cd avahi-0.6.31 ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var make 4.cd the subdirectories make Android.mk then,you will see Android.mk in all the subdirectories. ndk-build V=1 NDK_LOG=2 APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a"

Answer (score 0):

You should go to **avahi-core** and excute command `make Android.mk` , then you will find **Android.mk**.