# file request for: "0002-Add-uninstalled.pc.in-files.patch" from avahi for compiling for android

Tags: android, qt, zeroconf, avahi

I try to compile a Qt console project for Android that includes DNS services provided by avahi. As my shared libraries dns_sd.so are not compatible, I would try to compile avahi according to these links.

[Utilize Avahi Libraries in Android for mDNS Discovering](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.co.at/2015/12/utilize-avahi-libraries-in-android-for.html)

[Problems compiling avahi into Android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991668/problems-compiling-avahi-into-android-ndk-project)

What I cannot find is the file "0002-Add-uninstalled.pc.in-files.patch" from Avahi. Please share it with me, if you still have it available. I also contacted avahi directly but did not receive a response yet. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The files in the link below are accessible again.
[Utilize Avahi Libraries in Android for mDNS Discovering](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.co.at/2015/12/utilize-avahi-libraries-in-android-for.html)